# PHP Mysqli - Parameter binding AND escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

For database security do I need to do BOTH binding parameters in a prepared statement AND mysql_real_escape_string() on the input?

Thanks!

Comment: No! Bind parameters automatically escape quotes in strings, that's their purpose: so don't do it yourself unless you want erroneous escape characters in the saved values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, parameterised queries are fine on their own. As long as you keep all variable data in parameters, passed separately from the query, they can be picked up without any escape/unescape handling.

You shouldn't blanket-escape at the input phase in general - you don't know what kinds of escape (SQL, HTML, JS, ...) you're going to need until the point you actually inject a value into one of those string contexts. Applying all kinds of escapes over all input data will only lead to mangled and inconsistent input handling.